# Shared implementation of multiple interfaces in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I need to implement two interfaces, `GLView` and `MetalView`:

- `GLView` is subclass of `NSOpenGLView` (that is in turn subclass of `NSView`).
- `MetalView` is direct subclass of `NSView`.

Most of the implementation is shared between `GLView` and `MetalView` and I obviously do not want to copy-paste that.
In c++, I would have a template class `BaseViewImpl` that would take template parameter `BaseView` and I would use `BaseViewImpl<NSOpenGLView>` as the base class for `GLView` and `BaseViewImpl<NSView>` as the base for
`MetalView`.

How can I achieve the same in objective c?

Comment: Are you sure `GLView` needs to be a subclass of `NSOpenGLView`? Can you make it a subclass of `NSView` but override `makeBackingLayer` to return an `NSOpenGLLayer`?

Comment: @robmayoff I override few methods from NSOpenGLView, so GLView needs to be its subclass (I guess)

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be to simply put the common code into its own object and have each of `GLView` and `MetalView` own an instance of that object. You can make a protocol which both views implement to give them the same interface. Internally, they would pass the common requests onto the object they own.

Comment: Does that mean that in both classes I will need to define all functions I have implementations for and then forward them to this common object?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's busywork, but it gets the job done.

Comment: This is Objective-C. You don't need to implement every method, you can use message forwarding via -respondsToSelector:/-forwardInvocation: overrides if you feel that's cleaner.